# Not load content of previous state in History.js to know when the back button was pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, browser-history, history.js

I have implemented State Aware URL on ajax call using history.js(using pushState method). Now when I click back button of any browser, it should load content of previous state using my ajax method.For this I have done following:

```
$(function () {
History.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange', function () {
    if (typeof (manualStateChange) !== 'undefined' && manualStateChange == true) {        
    var State = History.getState();
    callingAjax(State.data.loadUrl);
    }
    manualStateChange = true;
  });
});
```

Any time I change the state programmatically, set the bool to false:

```
function pushfun(stateUrl) {
    manualStateChange = false;
    History.pushState({ loadUrl: stateUrl, rand: Math.random() }, document.title, stateUrl);
}
```

But this is not work when I go to another page and then click on browser's back button & again click browser's back button. It only removes browser url and not replacing content of previous state.